# GitLab remote yaml not triggered

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using a repository for all of our GitLab CI yaml project files, but when changing the CI yaml in this repository, the pipeline of the configured project does not trigger.

I try to explain.

I have the **project A** where it's `.gitlab-ci.yml` lies in a different repository and its configured like image below:

[image: remote ci yaml file]

But when I update the file `project-a/.gitlab-ci.yml` in the repository `platform/general-pipelines` the pipeline is not being triggered.

Should I create a Downstream pipeline for that and then trigger it from a job when the file changes?

I expected it to trigger the pipeline automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only half of the task that you need. You have created a pipeline .gitlab-ci.yml file in another repository, but the current repository does if it's upstream pipeline file was edited.

You have no trigger to start the pipeline.

While this may be possible to do using "Pipeline triggers" in CI/CD settings via API, I have worked around this by creating an "orchestrator" repository that has pipeline files for all the other repositories and it has its own pipeline, that can then trigger downstream pipelines.

Let's say you have "orchestrator" repository with files:

- .gitlab-ci.yml
- /pipelines/projectA-pipeline.yml

And and "projectA" repository, an empty one.

I follow these steps:

1. Edit settings in projectA to use custom pipeline location.
   [similar like you did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCanR.png)
2. In "orchestrator" edit /pipelines/projectA-pipeline.yml
   Nothing will happen yet. There is no trigger.

   ```yaml
     stage: build
     script:
       - echo "I am pipeline file from antoher repo, build stage"

     stage: test
     script: 
       - echo "I am pipeline file from antoher repo, test stage"

     stage: deploy
     script:
       - echo "I am pipeline file from antoher repo, deploy stage"
   ```
3. Then you create .gitlab-ci.yml in "orchestrator" repository.

   ```yaml
     01-pipeline-downstream:
       trigger:
         project: projectA
         strategy: depend
       rules:
         - if:
           changes:
             - pipelines/projectA-pipeline.yml
   ```

This pipeline will only run when the file for that downstream was changed.

The "depend" keyword is only added here so that orchestrator pipeline will wait on results of downstream pipeline stages before showing completed status.

This will trigger the downstream pipeline and will also add the possibility to trigger any downstream pipeline that you have added to "orchestrator" .gitlab-ci.yml. This pipeline will show up in both repositories.

["master" pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqzOo.png)
*This image has different task names, but it should make sense, I hope :)*

This also allows you to create rules to trigger only some stages of downstream pipeline. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html

However, if you change files in "projectA", this is a trigger and the pipeline for "projectA" will run regardless...